# How do I mount a persistent disk to a container volume?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm playing around with [Google's managed VM feature](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) and finding you can fairly easily create some interesting setups. However, I have yet to figure out whether it's possible to use [persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) to mount a volume on the container, and it seems not having this feature limits the usefulness of managed VMs for stateful containers such as databases.

So the question is: how can I mount the persistent disk that Google creates for my Compute engine instance, to a container volume?

Answer (score 2):

### Attaching a persistent disk to a Google Compute Engine instance

Follow [the official persistent-disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks) guide:

- Create a disk
- Attach to an instance [during instance creation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#attachdiskcreation), or [to a running instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#attachdiskrunninginstance)
- Use the tool `/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount` to mount the device file `/dev/disk/by-id/google-...`
- As noted by Faizan, use `docker run -v /mnt/persistent_disk:/container/target/path` to include the volume in the docker container

### Referencing a persistent disk in Google Container Engine

In this method, you specify the volume declaratively (after initializing it as mentioned above...) in the Replication Controller or Pod declaration. The following is a minimal excerpt of a replication controller JSON declaration. Note that the volume has to be declared read-only because no more than two instances may write to a persistent disk at one time.

```
{
    "id": "<id>",
    "kind": "ReplicationController",
    "apiVersion": "v1beta1",
    "desiredState": {
        "replicas": 3,
        "replicaSelector": {
            "name": "<id>"
        },
        "podTemplate": {
            "desiredState": {
                "manifest": {
                    "version": "v1beta1",
                    "id": "<id>",
                    "containers": [
                        {
                            "name": "<id>",
                            "image": "<docker_image>",
                            "volumeMounts": [
                                {
                                    "name": "persistent_disk",
                                    "mountPath": "/pd",
                                    "readOnly": true
                                }
                            ],
                            ...
                        }
                    ],
                    "volumes": [
                        {
                            "name": "persistent_disk",
                            "source": {
                                "persistentDisk": {
                                    "pdName": "<persistend_disk>",
                                    "fsType": "ext4",
                                    "readOnly": true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "labels": {
                "name": "<id>"
            }
        }
    },
    "labels": {
        "name": "<id>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your persistent disk is attached and mounted already to the instance, I believe you can use it as a data volume with your docker container. I was able to find docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) which explains the steps on how to manage data in containers.